# ionic2 - how to custom button size

Tags: css, ionic-framework

This is my screenshot for my sharing button
[image]

This screen size for iphone6 4.7inch, but if run it in iphone5 4inch which will crowded and deformed, so I want to change button size to more small.

**.html** file

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-note>分享：</ion-note>
      <button ion-fab color="wechat" (click)= "wechatshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-wechat"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab color="danger" (click)= "weiboshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-weibo"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab color="primary" (click)= "qqshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab color="wechat" (click)= "whatsappshare(new)"><ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab color="facebook" (click)= "FBshare(new)"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-row>
```

Update:

If I remove `ion-fab`, it will be like this

[image]

Comment: Is `ion-fab` obligatory? If not, you can remove it and style with css easily

Comment: If i remove 'ion-fab', the button change to black and background also change, I upload the image to question, check please

Comment: try to use `ion-button` instead of `ion-fab`

Comment: ion-button showing error for me

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Is it like this?
<ion-row>
 <ion-note>sharing：</ion-note>
<ion-button color="wechat" (click)= "wechatshare(new)"><ion-icon name="minan-wechat"></ion-icon></ion-button> 
<ion-row>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153185/discussion-between-yuyang-he-and-duannx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it..Thanks to @Duannx

add `class="btn"` in the `button`

**.html** file

```
<button ion-fab color="facebook" class="btn" (click)= "FBshare(new)"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
```

**.scss** file

```
.btn {
  display:block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px ;
}
```